# How to create localized handlebarsjs template?

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js

I have php backend that builds dynamic site with handlebars templates. Site must support UI localization by user preference (site has users authentication with UI settings for them). Now, all handlebars templates generated by php processor, for example:

```
{{!-- Template for dispatch table --}}
<table id="records" class="table-data">
    <caption>
        <h3>
            <div class="column-right"><span class="icon-clock"></span><span id="clock"></span></div>
            <div><span class="icon-database"></span><?php echo _('Records in the order for dispatching.'); ?></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </h3>
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><span class="icon-database"></span><?php echo _('Name'); ?></th>
            <th><span class="icon-clock"></span><?php echo _('Record Date'); ?></th>
            <th><span class="icon-user"></span><?php echo _('Client'); ?></th>
            <th><span class="icon-pencil"></span><?php echo _('Conclusion'); ?></th>
            <th><span class="icon-doc"></span><?php echo _('Status'); ?></th>
            <th><span class="icon-doc-text"></span><?php echo _('Doctor'); ?></th>
            <th><span class="icon-code"></span><?php echo _('Type'); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each records}}
        .................
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And it's not cool :( Too many `<?php echo ... ?>` in template.
May be there is some solution for this problem?

P.S.: Template generated on the backend but is compiled and works at the user side.

**UPDATE:**
I want to reduce work performed by backend. The best solution for me is transform dynamic hbs template to set of statics (by one for supported localization). For this purpose I want to compile template so that all `<?php echo _('...'); ?>` statements will be transomed to localy strings.
But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: what exactly is the problem??

Comment: @Jeff, I want to reduce work performed by server.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the use of `echo` statement you can use a Php template engine like Smarty. In this way, instead of using `echo` you will compile your template already written in a html file. This html file will also contain the handlebars directive, so it will be compiled by user side. But at this point, why don't you use only a Php template engine?That's depend on you . . .

Comment: PHP templates will work more quickly than `echo` statements in generated hbs? Can I precompile these templates for all languages?

Comment: You can precompile the templates in every way you want, regarding to performance using engine will be always slower than raw code but you have the advantages of separeted concerns and so better maintenance.